# NHibernate query count

Tags: nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate and I want to have a count of rows from database. Below is my code,

```
SearchTemplate template = new SearchTemplate();
            template.Criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(hotel));
            template.Criteria.Add(Restrictions.Lt("CheckOutDate", SelDate) || Restrictions.Eq("CheckOutDate", SelDate));
            template.Criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Canceled", "False"));
    int count = template.Criteria.SetProjection(Projections.Count("ID"));
```

It gives me an error when I try to compile app that says
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria' to 'int'"

I want to have a count of rows of the table hotel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `GetExecutableCriteria`:

```
SearchTemplate template = new SearchTemplate();
        template.Criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(hotel));
        template.Criteria.Add(Restrictions.Lt("CheckOutDate", SelDate) || Restrictions.Eq("CheckOutDate", SelDate));
        template.Criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Canceled", "False"));

var count = DoCount(template.Criteria, session /* your session */);

public long DoCount(DetachedCriteria criteria, ISession session)
{
     return Convert.ToInt64(criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session)
                   .SetProjection(Projections.RowCountInt64())
                   .UniqueResult());
}
```

On a side note, you should take a look at using [**NHibernate.Linq**](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/8/17/linq-for-nhibernate-examples/):

```
var result = (from h in Session.Linq<Hotel>()
             where h.CheckOutDate <= SelDate
             where h.Canceled != true
             select h).Count();
```

More information [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781056/nhibernate-linq-supported-operators/3782323#3782323).

Comment: How would I use it in my situation. How would I change the above code that I have posted so that it uses the function that you have provided?