# Finding the row with matching relations using HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am using Castle ActiveRecord and NHibernate.

I have an **Instance** class which has a many-to-many relationship with a **Component** class.  I would like to find the instance which is related to a specific set of components.  Is this possible in HQL (or anything else in NHibernate)?

The linq version of this function would be:

```
public Instance find(IEnumerable<Component> passed_components)
{
    return Instance.Queryable.Single(i => passed_components.All(x => i.Components.Contains(x)));
}
```

Of course the NHibernate linq implementation can't handle this.

I can write the HQL to do this for one of the components:

```
Instance.FindOne(new DetachedQuery("from Instance i where :comp in elements(i.Components)").SetParameter("comp", passed_components.First()));
```

But it looks like **in** only compares one item to a set, it can't compare a set to a set.

**EDIT:**

This is the best I could do:

```
IQueryable<Instance> q = Queryable;
foreach(var c in components) {
    q = q.Where(i => i.Components.Contains(c));
}
```

But this is very inefficient.  It adds a subselect to the SQL query for every where clause.  An unnecissarily long subselect at that.  It joins the Instance table, the Instance/Component join table, and the Component table.  It only needs the Instance/Component join table.

Because of the nature of my data, I am going to implement a hybrid solution.  Narrow down the instances in the query, then use linq to objects to get the correct one if necessary.
The code looks like this:

```
IQueryable<Instance> q = Queryable;
foreach(var c in components.Take(2)) {
    q = q.Where(i => i.Components.Contains(c));
}

var result = q.ToArray();
if(result.Length > 1) {
    return result.SingleOrDefault(i => !components.Except(i.Components).Any());
}
else return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **NHibernate.Linq** provider, the following should work:

```
var passed_components = new List<Component>();
var instance = session.Linq<Instance>()
                      .Where(i => !passed_components.Except(i.Components).Any())
                      .SingleOrDefault();
```

You can download the provider [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download) and read more about it [**here**](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/8/17/linq-for-nhibernate-examples/) and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781056/nhibernate-linq-supported-operators/3782323#3782323)**.

Comment: Are you sure this works?  I am pretty sure Contains only takes in a single object, not a list.  ActiveRecord comes with a Linq provider which does not allow this.  I also checked the NHibernate.Linq in nhcontrib, it doesn't work there either.

Comment: @oillio: My mistake, I apologize. However, I have edited the post for the code to compare if a list contains another one, following this http://bit.ly/aQSE31 . However, I'm not 100% it'll work with NHibernate.Linq.

Comment: That version is much better than my linq code above.  Unfortunatly, it won't work with NHibernate either.